# command line arguments rake task wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I have a very simple rake task, created by following [this tutorial](http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial). The rake task is as:

```
namespace :abc do
  task :arbitrary => :environment do
    Rails.application.config.method = ENV["CAT_METHOD"] || 1
    Rails.logger.debug "The method is #{Rails.application.config.method}"
  end
end
```

And I am calling this task as:

```
bundle exec rake abc:arbitrary CAT_METHOD=2
```

But it gives me this error.

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(0 for 1)
```

What wrong am I doing? I am pretty new to RoR. I am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2

Comment: `Rails.application.config.method` is creating a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line `Rails.application.config.method`. The standard method `Kernel#method` is used to retrieve a method object and (kind of) a reserved word since it is defined on all objects. To fix this, you must name your custom config differently, for example `Rails.application.config.cat_method`.

Comment: Thinking this as a possible reason, I also changed the method name to cat_method, but it was failing then too. I re-pulled the whole file from the CVS and then wrote this task from the scratch using method name cat_method and it works.